# Infinite series: which test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having troubling deciding which test to use for this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{\ln(n!)}{n+4^n}\right)$$

I tried altnerating test and ratio test but I couldn't get an answer. I also tried comparison test by comparing it to $\cfrac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{n}$, which ends up as a harmonic series.

Am I doing this right?

Thanks.

Comment: $\arctan(x)\lt x$ for small $x$, therefore, $$\arctan\left(\frac{\ln(n!)}{n+4^n}\right) \lt \frac{\ln(n!)}{n+4^n} \sim  \frac{n\ln(n)}{4^n} \lt \frac{n^2}{4^n} \lt \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: We need to show that $\frac{\log(n!)}{n+4^n}$ is a monotonic sequence if we want to use the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the alternating series test. Keep in mind that the arctangent of a positive number is positive.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Are you saying to set bn=1^n/(n+4^n)?

Comment: @Kenneth I'm saying very little, because I want to leave most of the work to you. I think this hint should be sufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan$ is a monotonous function. You have two possible outcomes: if the argument of $\arctan$ tends to zero, you can use $\arctan \approx x$ and proceed that way (if it decreases monotonically, it's proven convergent by the alternating series test). If it tends to infinity, the $\arctan$ goes toward its asymptote and the series diverges.

By applying the stirling approximation for $\ln n!$ and ignoring $n$ in the denominator, you quickly obtain asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Stirling approximation is working too hard. Better yet is $\ln(n!) \leq n\ln n$.

Comment: @Mike that's almost the same, just truncated a bit more :)